# Expressing the maximum function in terms of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, nonlinear-analysis

Suppose we have the following function for the positive part of a real number, which we define as:

> $ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $
>
> $f(x)=\max(x,0)$

And we generalize this function to matrices trivially by applying it elementwise

> $ f : \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $
>
> $ (f(A))_{i,j}=\max((A)_{i,j},0) $

The function $ f $ is obviously nonlinear on the space of $ m \times n $ matrices but as sometimes done with nonlinear operators I was hoping that perhaps I can embed the space into higher dimensions where I can represent $ f $ as a linear operator and then go back to the original space in a nonlinear fashion by clipping the unneeded terms. I would certainly appreciate all help on this and I kindly appreciate all efforts to of helpers.

Comment: What do mean mathematically by saying " can embed the space into higher dimensions where I can represent $f$ as linear operator "?

Comment: $f$ is piece wise linear though .

Comment: @Redshoes : yes, but does that help my representation efforts

Comment: @Redshoes : by embedding, I mean appending auxiliary rows and columns to the matrix and applying a linear transform to that as the max function

Comment: your method of embedding preserve differentiability , so when you go back (restrict domain to the subspace $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ ) you get a differentiable function